# Read csv files in subfolder

Tags: julia

I store data in csv format and put them in "Datasets" folder. I would like to read data just using their name like this: `CSV.read("name_of_data.csv")` without telling Julia the full path like: `CSV.read("Datasets/name_of_data.csv")`.

I tried to use `push!(LOAD_PATH,"Datasets")` but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the current working directory of Julia to `Datasets`. You can do it by writing `cd("Datasets")` before trying to read the file (assuming that `pwd()` returns you a parent directory of `Datasets` directory).

You can also write something like:

```
cd("Datasets") do
    CSV.read("name_of_data.csv")
end
```

to change the directory to `Datasets` only temporarily to read the files.

`LOAD_PATH` is used by Julia to decide which paths to consider as project environments or package directories when **loading code** (not data).

**EDIT**:

This is an example possible approach:

```
function expandpath(directories, filenames)
    fnset = Set(filenames)
    namemapping = Dict{String, String}()
    for d in directories
        for fn in readdir(d)
            if fn in fnset
                fullpath = joinpath(d, fn)
                if isfile(fullpath)
                    namemapping[fn] = fullpath
                end
            end
        end
    end
    collect(values(namemapping))
end
```

Where `directories` is a list of directories you want to search and `filenames` is a list of filenames. As a result you get a list of extended paths to file names that were found in the directories listed (keeping the last in case of duplicate).

Comment: This solved my need. But can I have something like "multiple working directory"? Because it's getting really cumbersome when I have many sub-directory to search. Say I have "Datasets_1",...,"Datasets_n", it's better if I can search in all of those directory as I can do with ```addpath``` function in Matlab.

Comment: I am adding a method that does the job to the answer. You might want to modify it if you want to use another method of resolution of duplicate names.